# How to watch object changes then assign to new object and format the array value?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

```
appointments: {
    monday: {
        isOpen: true,
        hours: [{
                   open: "10:10", close: "18:10",
               }]  
 },
    tuesday: {
        isOpen: true,
        hours: [{
                   open: "08:00", close: "13:00",
                },
                {
                   open: "14:00", close: "18:00",
               }]  
 },
},
```

This is my expected data format. Initially the `open` and `close` is a date object. I am trying to reinitialise it with new object and use `moment()` to format it when changes detected.

I am using `watch` to detect the changes when the value changed. But how can i assign to a new object and format the value?

```
watch: {
        appointments: {
            handler: function(val, oldVal) {
                // const test = val.map(item => {
                //       moment(...).format('HH:mm');
                //     return ..
                // })
            },
            deep: true
        },
    },
```

This is the error i get when i am trying with the method above.

```
TypeError: val.map is not a function
    at Proxy.handler (app.js:154268)
    at callWithErrorHandling (app.js:127648)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (app.js:127657)
    at Array.job (app.js:129519)
    at flushPreFlushCbs (app.js:127820)
    at flushJobs (app.js:127861)
    at flushJobs (app.js:127892)
```

Comment: check what comes in `val` (you can simply use a `console.log`) before `const test`. `map` is for arrays, most probably your `val` comes as something different

Comment: Ya, it's an object. But I tried `reduce` also same error.

Comment: both `map` and `reduce` are for arrays, not objects. You'll need to traverse through either values or keys of the object. If you post an example of logged object, I can then give an answer accordingly